# Flow update record multiple times

Tags: visual-workflow, update

I have a flow which update one record multiple times and I run into a soql query problem.

I have two objects A and B, the flow should copy the value of object A to B but only if the field is not null, because I want to keep the old information when there is nothing new.

To check if the field is null I query through all fields. Below you will see my screen from all my checks. Is there another way?

Maybe to store all necessary change and run the update one time at the end?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just like in Apex, you can't just run as many queries as you want. Start with a single variable, use a Get Records element to get the record to update, including all the fields you wish to check for, then use a a chain of Decision and Assignment variables to apply changes to the destination record selectively, and finally use a single Update Records element at the end.

Answer (score 0):

When we did this I created a formula for each field that used BLANKVALUE to check if the field to be updated was currently blank and, if it is, return the new value, otherwise return the existing values. It means retrieving the record to be updated as well, but you can then just do a record update and reference the formulae, you don't need any decisions or even an assignment.